# Not able to connect Visual Studio to Sonarqube server with self-signed certificate

Tags: sonarqube

[image]I am not able to connect my visual studio running on local environment to sonarqube server, though i can access the sonarqube server in browser(i am able to login as administrator using the same user id and password that i m entering in VS).
Also i am able to connect visual studio to sonarqube installed on local machine(using http://localhost:9000).
Can anyone please tell me what could be the reason that i m not able to connect VS to sonarqube server which is already accessible in browser.
I have tried to login using token too but that too isn't working.

Comment: Do you use a self-signed certificate on SonarQube server?

Comment: yes, the issue is resolved after adding it to trusted certificates.

Comment: Please add an answer how to do it.

Comment: hi @agabrys, you can follow this [link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows)  for the same